# Update a Singleton member property from a foreground service

Tags: java, android

I have a location tracking app. I have a Foreground service that when the app goes into the background, it continues to get the location. That part works fine. If I output the location I can see the different points and correct timestamps.

While in the background I need to POST that data to an API endpoint. My `GPSHeartbeat` class is a singleton and it exposes a function to let me update the Singletons location property.

While in the foreground, everything works fine. When in the background, the location IS updated, but the singleton has the last location from ***BEFORE*** it went into the background.

My `APICommunicator` is firing in the background on its interval like it should, it just doesn't have the correct Location.

Here is the broadcast receiver that is responsible for listening to the Foreground services location change.

**This works fine in the background and in the foreground.** It is successfully getting the updated location.

```
private void onNewLocation(Location location)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNewLocationRec'd: " + location);

        mLocation = location;

        // Notify anyone listening for broadcasts about the new location.
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION, location);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

        // Update notification content if running as a foreground service.
        if (serviceIsRunningInForeground(this)) {
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
    }
```

The `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class of an Activity called `HomeActivity`. This gets the CORRECT location from the service. If I output the log, it is the same as what the Service broadcast.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private GPSHeartbeat   mGPSHeartbeat;

    private GPSReceiver myReceiver;
    private LocationUpdatesService mService = null;
    private       boolean           mBound             = false;

    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder binder = (LocationUpdatesService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound   = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            mService = null;
            mBound   = false;
        }
    };

    private void GPSBeginRequestingUpdates()
    {
        //Wait 5 seconds to spin up
        (new Handler()).postDelayed(this::StartGPSUpdates, 5000);

    }

    private void StartGPSUpdates()
    {
        mService.requestLocationUpdates();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myReceiver = new GPSReceiver();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mGPSHeartbeat = GPSHeartbeat.instance(getApplicationContext()).setInterval(6);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdatesService.class), mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationUpdatesService.ACTION_BROADCAST));
        GPSBeginRequestingUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }


    private class GPSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationUpdatesService.EXTRA_LOCATION);
            if (location != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "\nonReceived New Location: " + GPSUtils.getLocationText(location));
                GPSHeartbeat.instance(context.getApplicationContext()).SetLocation(location);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The Singleton. The SetLocation() **does** receive the correct location. It is only during my POST request that the `APICommunicator` is using the `GPSHeartbeat`'s old location. Even though it was just updated.

**How do I make sure I update to the correct location?**

```
  public class GPSHeartbeat extends Service {
    private static          String                 TAG       = "GPSHeartbeat";
    private static volatile GPSHeartbeat           _instance;
    private final           WeakReference<Context> mContextRef;
    private                 Boolean                isRunning = false;
    private                 int                    mInterval;

    private Location mLocation;

    private Handler         mHandler;
    private ExecutorService mExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private Future          mLongRunningTaskFuture;
    private Runnable        mStatusChecker   = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try {
                tick(); //this function can change value of mInterval.
            }
            finally {
                if (isRunning()) {
                    // 100% guarantee that this always happens, even if your update method throws an exception
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private GPSHeartbeat(Context context)
    {
        mContextRef = new WeakReference<>(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static GPSHeartbeat instance(Context context)
    {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new GPSHeartbeat(context);
        } else {
            if (!context.equals(_instance.mContextRef.get())) {
                _instance = null;
                _instance = new GPSHeartbeat(context);
            }
        }

        return _instance;
    }

    public void SetLocation(Location loc)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "setLocation(): " + loc);
        this.mLocation = loc;
    }

    public GPSHeartbeat setInterval(int interval)
    {
        this.mInterval = interval * 1000;
        return this;
    }


    public void start()
    {
        if (isRunning()) return;
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mLongRunningTaskFuture = mExecutorService.submit(mStatusChecker);
        mStatusChecker.run();
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        if (mHandler != null) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
        }
        if (mLongRunningTaskFuture != null) {
            //kill the task:
            try {
                mLongRunningTaskFuture.cancel(true);
                mLongRunningTaskFuture = null;
                mHandler               = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to cancel task: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
        isRunning = false;

    }

    public Location currentLocation()
    {
        return mLocation;
    }


    public boolean isRunning()
    {
        return isRunning;
    }

    private void tick()
    {
        // Fire off the APICommuncator.Post() method
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
    }
```

The APICommuncator

```
public class APICommuncator
{
    private static          String                 TAG = "APICommuncator";
    private static volatile APICommuncator          _instance;
    private final           WeakReference<Context> mContextRef;

    private GPSHeartbeat _gpsHeartbeat;


    private APICommuncator(Context context)
    {
        mContextRef     = new WeakReference<>(context.getApplicationContext());
        _gpsHeartbeat   = GPSHeartbeat.instance(context.getApplicationContext());

    }

    public static APICommuncator i(Context context)
    {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new APICommuncator(context);
        } else {
            if (!context.equals(_instance.mContextRef.get())) {
                _instance = null;
                _instance = new APICommuncator(context);
            }
        }

        return _instance;
    }

    public void Post(){
        // Do the background thing and grab
        // getLocationNode() which gets the OLD location before it went to the background.
    }


    private JSONObject getLocationNode()
    {

        Location location = _gpsHeartbeat.currentLocation();
        if (location == null) {
            return null;
        }

        JSONObject node = null;
        try {
            node = new JSONObject();
            node.put("Latitude", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            node.put("Longitude", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            node.put("HAccuracy", String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));
            node.put("VAccuracy", String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));
            node.put("Altitude", String.valueOf(location.getAltitude()));
            node.put("Speed", String.valueOf(location.getSpeed() * 2.237));
            node.put("Heading", String.valueOf(location.getBearing()));
            node.put("Timestamp", String.valueOf((location.getTime() / 1000)));
        }
        catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return node;
    }
}
```

In the Manifest:

```
   <service
        android:name=".gpsheartbeat.GPSHeartbeat"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <service
        android:name=".gpsheartbeat.LocationUpdatesService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't see that you are using foreground service. Not foreground service would be killed very soon after the application goes background. Plus communication with API should be in the scope of foreground service because activity could be killed by the system.

Comment: @aandy-shpak I have updated the question with the Full activity that shows the binding of the service.